# how to pass a variable from one form to a textBoxChanged event handler on another form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

On Form one i need to send the listbox.SelectedIndex to second Form:

```
private void btnEditWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form editWord = new editWord(listBox.SelectedIndex);


        editWord.ShowDialog();


    }
```

Second Form: the selected index variable does not exist in current context.

```
public editWord(int value)

    {
        InitializeComponent();

       int selectedIndex = value;

    }

private void wordTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string word = (dictionaryDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[selectedIndex]["Word"].ToString());

        wordTextBox.Text = word;

    }
```

Comment: Add either a constructor in which you will inject the shared value between the forms, or consider your forms as objects, so they can have properties. So write yourself a property that shall be accessible publicly, and you're done.

Comment: Just move the `int selectedIndex;` outside of the constructor, to make it global to the second form and then in the constructor `selectedIndex = value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have commented your question,but just to make it clear, your second form code should look like this:

```
int selectedIndex=-1;

public editWord(int value)

{
    InitializeComponent();

    selectedIndex = value;

}

private void wordTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string word = (dictionaryDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[selectedIndex]["Word"].ToString());

    wordTextBox.Text = word;

}
```

The problem with your provided code is that the scope of `selectedIndex` is only the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Just move the int selectedIndex; outside of the constructor, to make it global to the second form and then in the constructor selectedIndex = value;

Comment: If you are going to copy my comment as an answer,at least remove my nick and time part :)